# Google maps WebGL support

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have seen 3D map of Google Maps JavaScript API WebGL beta. 3D buildings visualization was so beautiful and we want to use it. I have few queries regarding this API.
-- How will be the licensing for this product when we use for commercial purpose.
-- Is their support for adding our own building data to Google cloud, so that they can be rendered using     Google webGL API.
-- I have seen making buildings transparent and highlighting with some color in the example given in URL: https://geo-devrel-io2021-travel.web.app/#hotels
I wanted to change the buildings rendering such as color, transparency, and all in the same manner. I am not able to find proper documentation for implementing such, Is there any documentation for implementing such features using Google WebGL API? screenshot is shown below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXMEg.png)

Thanks,
Gireesh

Comment: Feature requests added in https://issuetracker.google.com/194989591. Please star issue if you have similar requests.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the exact mechanism by which the existing building is no longer visible, but the new building with highlighting was extruded using ThreeJS.

```
//hotels color
  const hotelMaterial = new MeshStandardMaterial({
    transparent: true,
    opacity: 0.5,
    color: 0x00ff00
  });

  const roofShape = new Shape();
  points.forEach((p, i) => {
    i === 0 ? roofShape.moveTo(p.z, p.x) : roofShape.lineTo(p.z, p.x);
  });

  const extrudeSettings = {
    depth: BUILDING_HEIGHT,
    bevelEnabled: false
  };
  const roofGeometry = new ExtrudeGeometry(roofShape, extrudeSettings);
  const roof = new Mesh(roofGeometry, hotelMaterial);
  roof.lookAt(UP_VECTOR);
  roof.rotateZ(Math.PI * 1.5);
  scene.add(roof);
```

I'll dig a bit more into this.